# VB.NET: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'

Tags: vb.net, events

I am getting an `ArgumentException` when trying to add event handler in VB.NET.

```
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'
```

The exception occurs here:

```
AddHandler MyClass.SomePropertyChanged, AddressOf MySecondClass.HandleSomePropertyChanged
```

Classes:

```
Class MyClass    
    Public Event SomePropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SomePropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Protected Overridable Sub OnSomePropertyChanged(ByVal e As SomePropertyChangedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent SomePropertyChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

    'I'm raising the event like this:
    OnSomePropertyChanged(New SomePropertyChangedEventArgs("Rating", 0.09))

End Class

Class MySecondClass    
    Public Sub HandleSomePropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SomePropertyChangedEventArgs)
        '...
    End Sub
End Class
```

EventArgs I have defined as:

```
Public Class SomePropertyChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property PropertyName As String
    Public Property Value As Object
End Class
```

I am not getting what is the problem here-

Comment: pass the PropertyName ,Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to suggest that at this line:

```
AddHandler MyClass.SomePropertyChanged, AddressOf MySecondClass.HandleSomePropertyChanged
```

your `MySecondClass` variable is `Nothing`.

Comment: This was exactly the problem due to a bug in elsewhere in my code.